# placing the .hbm files where we can access in both by test and src

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, testng, spring-test

I have a project which is having the maven project structure as below

[image: project structure]

I need to use same .hbm files in test cases as well as in src code

My Testcases are in TestNG+Spring

Where i have configured session factory as below

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>Message.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>MessageClass.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>MessageId.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">saartha</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So i am getting FileNotfoundException

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Message.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Help me where i can place the hbm files, or any other way to configure the session factory

Comment: Well of course they aren't found as they aren't in the root of the class path. Prefix with `com/saartha/message`...

Comment: i tried that.. but while running testcases it is not available in test case classpath

Comment: They are in the wrong part of your application, place them in `src/main/resources/` instead of `/src/main/java/` in the same path then it should work. Only .java/.class files are expected to be in `src/main/java` hence the `java` thing :).